# Is it possible to create an optional literal in Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift, option-type

I have explained my query in the code snippet below. I am looking for this type of syntax for Obj-C interoperability. Specifically I see a difference in behaviour of `aCoder.encode(count, forKey: "count")` API when count is Int (non-optional) vs Int? (optional)

```
import Foundation

let num = 5
// Swift's type system will infer this as Int (non-optional)
print(type(of: num))
// Prints: Int

let optNum: Int? = 5
// This is explicitly typed as an optional Int
print(type(of: optNum))
// Prints Optional<Int>
```

Is it possible to use a literal to implicitly type a var/let to optional?

```
// let imlicitOptional = 5?
// print(type(of: imlicitOptional))
// The above line should print: Optional<Int>

// or

// let imlicitOptional = num?
// print(type(of: imlicitOptional))
// The above line should print: Optional<Int>
```

Comment: Literals don't have types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Optional` is a plain `enum` not any specific magic type. So, you can create a value using `Optional`:

```
let implicitOptional = Optional(5)
print(type(of: implicitOptional)) // Optional<Int>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you need this but you can do like this

```
let opt = 5 as Int?
// or
let opt = Optional(5)
// or
let opt = 5 as Optional // thanks to vacawama for this
```

Actually you can even create an operator that returns an optional but I think it's kinda useless.

```swift
postfix operator >?
postfix func >?<T>(value: T) -> T? {
    return Optional(value) // or return value as T?
}

let a = 5>?
```